# Using minGW to create a static library for use with Intel Fortran

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, g++, mingw, intel-fortran

Let me start off by stating that I am not a programmer. I am a Mech Eng that has to use code from various other engineers and assemble them into an executable.  The main code is fortran and is compiled using Intel Fortran via Visual Studio 2008 (yes, very old version).  One of the supporting codes is c++. Normally, I compile the c++ code using the built in Visual c++ compiler into a static lib then link the static lib into the main fortran code. The latest update of the c++ code will not compile in the 2008 Visual c++ because it needs the /permissive option. So, I have tried to get the c++ code compile into a static lib using g++.  I get unresolved external symbol errors when doing this.  The c++ code I use it very complex so I decided to make a simple example to see if I could get that to work.  I am getting similar errors but since it is so simple I can post it here.I am sure someone on this forum can fix it in a few min. Here is the example c++ code:

```
    #include <fstream>
#include <iostream>


#include <string.h>



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------



extern "C"
{
void add_2_nums(double *x,double *y,double *z);


}




 extern "C" void add_2_nums(double *x,double *y,double *z)
{
    
    *z = *x + *y;


    return;
}
```

I compiled it using both g++/ar and mingw32-g++/mingw32-gcc-ar.  Here is an example command:

```
mingw32-g++   -s -Iincludem -Iincludev   -c   -O2 -DNDEBUG add_2_nums.cpp
mingw32-gcc-ar r add_2_nums.lib add_2_nums.o
```

Some of the compiler options I used was from this forum in trying to resolve the errors and may not be appropriate.

Here is the simple fortran code:

```
program gcc_fun

implicit none

! Variables
real*8 x,y,z

x = 3.d0
y = 17.d0

call add_2_nums(x,y,z)

! Body of gcc_fun
print *, 'Z = ', z

end program gcc_fun
```

I use the C,Reference compile option and the rest default inside the Visual Studio environment.  Here are the errors I get:

```
    Error   1    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev referenced in    function ___tcf_0  add_2_num.lib(static_lib_test.o)    
Error   2    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev referenced in function __GLOBAL__sub_I_add_2_nums   add_2_num.lib(static_lib_test.o)    
Error   3    fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals    Debug\gcc_fun.exe
```